# Make retrofit fetch new data from server only if localy cached data is older than 5 minutes

Tags: android, kotlin, caching, retrofit

I have to make my retrofit client fetch new data from the server only if the locally cached data is older than 5 minutes or if it doesn't exist

```kotlin
    private fun initRetrofit(){

        val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://newsapi.org/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()

        val service = retrofit.create(NewsService::class.java)
        val call = service.getCurrentNews(
            "bbc-news",
            "top",
            "75702474c08c4c0c96c4081147233679"
        )

        call.enqueue(object : Callback<NewsResponse> {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<NewsResponse>, response: Response<NewsResponse>) {
                if (response.isSuccessful){
                    val body = response.body()
                    addDataSet(body!!.articles)
                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<NewsResponse>, t: Throwable) {
                val alertDialogBuilder = AlertDialog.Builder(this@MainActivity)
                alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Greška")
                alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Ups, došlo je do pogreške.")
                alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("U REDU"){ _, _ -> }
                alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false)
                alertDialogBuilder.show()

            }
        } )
    }
```

It is shown above how I am currently using a retrofit. I've used okhttpclient and interceptors before, but I'm not sure how exactly I should do it.

I made up with this now, but it's not working as it shoud.

```kotlin
    private fun retrofit(okHttpClient: OkHttpClient) = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://newsapi.org/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .build()

    private fun okHttp(cache: Cache): OkHttpClient {
        return OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .cache(cache)
                .addNetworkInterceptor(CacheInterceptor())
                .build()
    }

    private fun httpCache(application: Application): Cache {
        return Cache(application.applicationContext.cacheDir, CACHE_SIZE)
    }

    class CacheInterceptor : Interceptor {
        override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): okhttp3.Response {
            val request = chain.request()
            val originalResponse = chain.proceed(request)

            val shouldUseCache = request.header(CACHE_CONTROL_HEADER) != CACHE_CONTROL_NO_CACHE
            if(!shouldUseCache) return originalResponse

            val cacheControl = CacheControl.Builder()
                    .maxAge(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                    .build()

            return originalResponse.newBuilder()
                    .header(CACHE_CONTROL_HEADER, cacheControl.toString())
                    .build()
        }

    }
```

A with all this, I just build retrofit with:
`val retrofit = retrofit(okHttp(httpCache(application )))`
Sometimes it works fine, sometimes gets data but still call `onFailure()`, it seems that call was enqueued twice, and sometimes just throw `onFailure()`. I'm am not sure if he is using local cache or is he sending requests every time.

Comment: Probably using Cache module of retrofit or using an interceptor

Comment: Yes, I know, but how to implement it here exacly

Comment: @Amin Dou you know how to implement that properly??

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what are you looking for. If there's a strict requirement to be exactly 5mins and the backend cannot/don't set proper cache headers (which even if they do, you cannot expect a 100% guarantee of the answer being served from cache), you have two options, either add and interceptor which mimics a cache by storing request and successful responses on RAM/DB (which is a bit weird) or try to cache some responses on your repository which is also abnormal. Specially if you're going to cache a lot of api calls. I personally see this requirement risky there all a lit of circumstances

Comment: You may run out of memory, your authentication might change, the user id might change, there all a lot of situations which you have to clear them all, maybe if you attach your APIs interface, and tell what APIs are going to follow this pattern, I can understand your case a little bit better, but your question seems a little bit different than normal caches (probably I'm wrong by misunderstanding your requirements)

Answer (score 3):

You need cache interceptor like this:

```
public class CacheInterceptor implements Interceptor {
    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Response response = chain.proceed(chain.request());

        CacheControl cacheControl = new CacheControl.Builder()
                .maxAge(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES) // 5 minutes cache
                .build();

        return response.newBuilder()
                .removeHeader("Pragma")
                .removeHeader("Cache-Control")
                .header("Cache-Control", cacheControl.toString())
                .build();
    }
}
```

Add this interceptor with `Cache` to your `OkHttpClient` like this:

```
File httpCacheDirectory = new File(applicationContext.getCacheDir(), "http-cache");
int cacheSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024; // 10 MiB
Cache cache = new Cache(httpCacheDirectory, cacheSize);
OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addNetworkInterceptor(new CacheInterceptor())
            .cache(cache)
            .build();
```

Comment: It seems like this one still makes network calls even if data is less than like 5 minutes old. Is there a way to not make the call at all if it's less than 5 minutes?

Answer (score 1):

In your business logic, you will want to check your local cache for the existence of the data or if there is data if it has been 5 minutes since it has been updated. If the criteria is met to make the request with retrofit; then the request should be made, the cache updated with the timestamp the data was saved in the cache.

If the data is in the cache and less than 5 minutes, then the cached data is returned.

This is a great read to get you started https://developer.android.com/jetpack/guide#overview