# Make retrofit fetch new data from server only if localy cached data is older than 5 minutes or it doesn't exist at all

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, okhttp

I have to make my retrofit client fetch new data from the server only if the locally cached data is older than 5 minutes or if it doesn't exist

```kotlin
class NewsServices {

    companion object{
        private const val CACHE_CONTROL_HEADER = "Cache-Control"
        private const val CACHE_CONTROL_NO_CACHE = "no-cache"
        private const val CACHE_SIZE = 5 * 1024 * 1024L
        private const val BASE_URL = "https://newsapi.org/"
        private const val SOURCE = "bbc-news"
        private const val SORTBY = "top"
        private const val APIKEY = "75702474c08c4c0c96c4081147233679"
    }

    fun getCall(application: Application): Call<NewsResponse> {
        val retrofit = retrofit(okHttp(httpCache(application )))
        val service = retrofit.create(NewsService::class.java)
        return service.getCurrentNews(SOURCE, SORTBY, APIKEY)
    }

    private fun retrofit(okHttpClient: OkHttpClient) = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .build()

    private fun okHttp(cache: Cache): OkHttpClient {
        return OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .cache(cache)
                .addInterceptor(getLoggingInterceptor())
                .addNetworkInterceptor(CacheInterceptor())
                .build()
    }

    private fun httpCache(application: Application): Cache {
        return Cache(application.applicationContext.cacheDir, CACHE_SIZE)
    }

    private fun getLoggingInterceptor(): HttpLoggingInterceptor {
        val loggingInterceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
        loggingInterceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BASIC)
        return loggingInterceptor
    }

    class CacheInterceptor : Interceptor {

        override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): okhttp3.Response {
            val request = chain.request()
            request.newBuilder().header(CACHE_CONTROL_HEADER, "public, only-if-cached, max-stale=" + 5).build()
            return chain.proceed(request)


//            val request = chain.request()
//            val originalResponse = chain.proceed(request)
//
//            val shouldUseCache = request.header(CACHE_CONTROL_HEADER) != CACHE_CONTROL_NO_CACHE
//            if(!shouldUseCache) return originalResponse
//
//            val cacheControl = CacheControl.Builder()
//                    .maxAge(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
//                    .build()
//
//            return originalResponse.newBuilder()
//                    .header(CACHE_CONTROL_HEADER, cacheControl.toString())
//                    .build()
        }

    }

}
```

Here is what I have for now. In the log, I can see that every time, two GET requests are sent to the server, and I'm not sure if he is using cache anyway. Bellow is listed log.

```kotlin
2021-05-02 21:18:43.687 1302-1302/com.demo.factorynews W/emo.factorynew: Accessing hidden method Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup;-><init>(Ljava/lang/Class;I)V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2021-05-02 21:18:43.731 1302-1562/com.demo.factorynews I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: --> GET https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?&source=bbc-news&sortBy=top&apiKey=75702474c08c4c0c96c4081147233679
2021-05-02 21:18:43.766 1302-1302/com.demo.factorynews W/Looper: Slow Looper main: Activity com.demo.factorynews/.MainActivity is 321ms late (wall=378ms running=0ms ClientTransaction{ callbacks=[android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem] lifecycleRequest=android.app.servertransaction.ResumeActivityItem }) because of 1 msg, msg 1 took 345ms (seq=2 h=android.app.ActivityThread$H w=110)
2021-05-02 21:18:43.768 1302-1302/com.demo.factorynews W/Looper: Slow Looper main: Activity com.demo.factorynews/.MainActivity is 700ms late (wall=0ms running=0ms ClientTransaction{ callbacks=[android.app.servertransaction.TopResumedActivityChangeItem] }) because of 2 msg, msg 1 took 345ms (seq=2 h=android.app.ActivityThread$H w=110), msg 2 took 378ms (seq=3 late=321ms h=android.app.ActivityThread$H w=159)
2021-05-02 21:18:43.857 1302-1610/com.demo.factorynews I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: --> GET https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?&source=bbc-news&sortBy=top&apiKey=75702474c08c4c0c96c4081147233679
2021-05-02 21:18:43.871 1302-1302/com.demo.factorynews E/ActivityInjector: get life cycle exception
    java.lang.ClassCastException: android.os.BinderProxy cannot be cast to android.app.servertransaction.ClientTransaction
        at android.app.ActivityInjector.checkAccessControl(ActivityInjector.java:24)
        at android.app.Activity.onResume(Activity.java:1859)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onResume(FragmentActivity.java:456)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1453)
        at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:8050)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4287)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4329)
        at android.app.servertransaction.ResumeActivityItem.execute(ResumeActivityItem.java:52)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:176)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)
        at android.app.ClientTransactionHandler.executeTransaction(ClientTransactionHandler.java:57)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivityLocally(ActivityThread.java:5358)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$3600(ActivityThread.java:230)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2078)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7551)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:995)
2021-05-02 21:18:44.269 1302-1562/com.demo.factorynews I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: <-- 200 https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?&source=bbc-news&sortBy=top&apiKey=75702474c08c4c0c96c4081147233679 (537ms, unknown-length body)
2021-05-02 21:18:44.579 1302-1610/com.demo.factorynews I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: <-- 200 https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?&source=bbc-news&sortBy=top&apiKey=75702474c08c4c0c96c4081147233679 (722ms, unknown-length body)
```

Comment: That is my question too if you look better, but people just stopped responding to it, will delete him after the bounty expires

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just save your cache in room/sqlite/file and save last update date in shared preferences. Create the repository class with local and remote data sources. Fetch the data from the local data source if last update date is less than 5 minutes, otherwise fetch it from remote source.

Or you can try to use okhttp capabilities: you need cache interceptor like this:

```
public class CacheInterceptor implements Interceptor {
    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Response response = chain.proceed(chain.request());

        CacheControl cacheControl = new CacheControl.Builder()
                .maxAge(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES) // 5 minutes cache
                .build();

        return response.newBuilder()
                .removeHeader("Pragma")
                .removeHeader("Cache-Control")
                .header("Cache-Control", cacheControl.toString())
                .build();
    }
}
```

Add this interceptor with Cache to your OkHttpClient like this:

```
File httpCacheDirectory = new File(applicationContext.getCacheDir(), "http-cache");
int cacheSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024; // 10 MiB
Cache cache = new Cache(httpCacheDirectory, cacheSize);
OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addNetworkInterceptor(new CacheInterceptor())
            .cache(cache)
            .build();
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I've been creating cacheInterceptor wrong all the time.
If you want, go on this question [Make retrofit fetch new data from server only if localy cached data is older than 5 minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67337923/make-retrofit-fetch-new-data-from-server-only-if-localy-cached-data-is-older-tha), it's mine too. And post same answer so i can give you bounty of 50 rep and delete that question.